# System function seems to ignore quote marks

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I'm running the following code (on Windows 7, if it makes a difference):

```
char temp[20000];
sprintf_s(temp, 20000, "\"C:\\Program Files\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe\" \"http://www.tvtak.com/servlet/Gateway/?C=addShows&channel=%s&show=%s\"", _channels[chId], name);
system(temp);
```

On running, the console displays:

> 'C:\Program' is not recognized as an
> internal or external command, operable
> program or batch file.
>
> 'channel' is not recognized as an internal or
> external command, operable program or
> batch file.
>
> 'show' is not recognized
> as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

But when I get the value of 'temp' via QuickWatch and paste it to CMD, it works fine. What's going on here?

I should mention that the parameters I'm appending to the string contain non-latin characters. Could this have something to do with it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are better off with `CreateProcess()` to avoid cmd.exe's quoting hell. But if you must use `system()` you can simply append `if 1==1` to the beginning of your command so it doesn't remove the quotes for you.

```
system("if 1==1 \"C:\Program...");
```

For more information about this issue, run `cmd.exe /?` and look for `/S`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put entire string into yet another pair of quotation marks. And try to avoid C-style strings in C++ code.